# Query String Issues

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello i trying to build ordinary Query String Parameters for HttpWebResponse.
I go to **www.ex.com?PageId=2&UserId=123** and if i change the PageId or UserId by my self all works fine  in the web,but when i sending this request in my HttpWebResponse it not working.
*I was working with Query String Parameters many times and this one seems like the all others no some thing special (fill Query String Parameters and send) but it's not working.*

What i am doing wrong?

This my code

```
HttpWebResponse Account =RedirectToUrl("https://www.ex.com/current.aspx?PageId=02.03.2014&UserId=13.04.2014&ltFilterSelected=none)

     private HttpWebResponse RedirectToUrl(string RedirectUrl)
            {

    HttpWebRequest redirectRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(RedirectUrl);
    redirectRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    redirectRequest.CookieContainer = _cookies;
    redirectRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)"; redirectRequest.Method = "GET";
    redirectRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    redirectRequest.Timeout = 15000;
    HttpWebResponse RedirectResponse = (HttpWebResponse)redirectRequest.GetResponse();
     return RedirectResponse;

            }
```

Comment: No, i just get the page with default filters setings

Comment: https://www.ex.com or https://www.xe.com ???

Comment: ex i mean like example, i can't write the real name of web site and user+pasword  becouse you need to login to see this page but the query string is right i checked that i even copied  him from webpage to project and still nothing

Comment: can you define what is the "working fine", here its seems that you try to find some redirect code.

Comment: "working fine" that mean when i on page 1- www.ex.com/Page1.aspx  and i can change it to www.ex.com/Page2.aspx?PageId=2&UserId=123 i see the  Page2 with PageId=2 and UserId=123 (fillter works) ,But when i send the same reques in function it's shows me the Page2 But with out the PageId=2 UserId=123 fillter

Comment: Maybe the page is checking for the referral address and if its outside the domain it rejects the query string and set it to normal.

Comment: The code above is do something else, is just read the redirect response... how you use that ? What the code do here is different from what you do with your hand.

Comment: When i get the RedirectResponse i read it with  StreamReader and i see the page but it like i send requset www.ex.com/Page2.aspx with out the PageId=2&UserId=12  and  "What the code do here is different from what you do with your hand."-- this is the problem nothing it the same

Comment: First check how filters are set on website.. through javascript or directly from server in response to the first GET request, use firebug's Net panel in Firefox or Chrome's developer tools to debug then use Fiddler and match your HttpWebRequest's headers with browser's headers (browser also sends some extra headers that you don't need like DNT).

Comment: I cheked this filters set  directly from server in response,and headres only this is missing(
Connection=Keep-Alive;
Content-Encoding=gzip;
Content-Length=30648;
Content-Type=text/html; charset=utf-8;
Date=Sun, 13 Apr 2014 10:17:15 GMT;
) but if i dont wrong you cant change them or set